# Jasmine Mock for nested Object in Angulartics

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angulartics

I have an *Angular 2* project. In that project I have imported the *Angulartics npm package* and injected it into one of my components. 
In my component I am making a single call that I need to mock for an existing unit test.

```
this.angulartics2.eventTrack.next({ action: 'Track my event'});
```

In my test spec file I have done the following:

1. Added this in `beforeEach`:

   ```
   mockAngulartics2 = jasmine.createSpyObj<Angulartics2>('angulartics2', ['eventTrack']);
   ```
2. Added this to providers:

   ```
   { provide: Angulartics2, useValue: mockAngulartics2 },
   ```

When I run my test, I get the following error back. What is the correct way to mock the `angulartics2.eventTrack.next` object?

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.angulartics2.eventTrack.next({ action: 'Track my event' })') in config/spec-bundle.js (line 145931)

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining about the call to `next` only.
You correctly created a spy object for `eventTrack` but not for `next`. So in between 1) and 2), you can do:

`mockAngulartics2.eventTrack = jasmine.createSpyObj('angulartics2', ['next']);`

I had an issue mocking `Angulartics2` and you lead me on the right way, so, thanks!